# Problem with DataLoader GraphQL returning wrong data

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js, dataloader

I developed an API using node with GraphQL, when I add the DataLoaders, the resolvers starts returning wrong data, like I pass 4 Ids [3, 3, 1, 2], the batch function find in Database and return ordered like [1, 2, 3] and when return to the resolver, the first object who has id 3, receive the response with id 1.

```
Project Packages versions ->
    "dataloader": "1.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.11.0",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-fields": "^2.0.3",
    "graphql-tools": "^6.2.4",
```

I also tried to use the dataloader latest version, but didn't worked

Follow my code.

```
Resolver ->

Address: {
        idCity: (parent, args, { db, dataloaders: { cityLoader } }: { db: DbConnection, dataloaders: DataLoaders }, info: GraphQLResolveInfo) => {
            return cityLoader.load({ info, key: parent.get('idCity') })
                .catch(handleError);
        }
    },
```

```
Data Loader Factory ->

cityLoader: new DataLoader<DataLoaderParam<number>, CityInstance>(
                (params: DataLoaderParam<number>[]) => CityLoader.batchCities(this.db.City, params, this.requestedFields),
                {
                    cacheKeyFn: (param: DataLoaderParam<number[]>) => param.key
                }
            ),
```

```
DataLoaderParam ->

export interface DataLoaderParam<T> {
    key: T;
    info: GraphQLResolveInfo;
}
```

```
City Loader ->

export class CityLoader {
    static async batchCities(City: CityModel, params: DataLoaderParam<number>[], requestedFields: RequestedFields) {
        const ids: number[] = params.map(item => item.key);

        return City["findAll"]({
            where: { id: { $in: ids } },
            attributes: requestedFields.getFields(params[0].info, { keep: ['id'], exclude: [] })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No, if you solve tell me please how can I do.

Answer (score 1):

I recently was running into this issue as well. I think you might have a similar problem to the one I had.

Mongo's $in operator doesn't guarantee order. So if you have a query where it has something like `_id: {$in: [1,2,3]}` it could be be returned in 2,3,1.

This is outlined in the docs for dataloader (although not in big and red enough font like maybe it should be)

> There are a few constraints this function must uphold:

> The Array of values must be the same length as the Array of keys.
> Each index in the Array of values must correspond to the same index in the Array of keys.

So my issue (and I assume yours) is that the order of the input doesn't match the order of the output. So as a stopgap I did this:

```
const sortOrder = new Map<string, number>()
for (let i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
  sortOrder.set(IDs[i], i)
}
objects.sort((a, b) => (sortOrder.get(a._id) > sortOrder.get(b._id) ? 1 : -1))
```

A better solution would be to extend dataloader to allow a mapping/matching function